# How to show array in html form is an autocomplete search field in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, codeigniter

I made an autocomplete search field using codeigniter, the result is coming in an array like

```
({"destination":"Accra"},{"destination":"Lagos"})
```

and I want to convert it into the html and show in drop down of input field. I tried many different method but could succeed, Kindly help me out.

Here is the code of my view, model and controller:

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>


</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country_id').keyup( function() {
        var min_length = 0; 
    var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { term: $("#country_id").val()},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
});
}); 
</script>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="country_id" id="country_id" onKeyUp="do_search();" >

  <ul id="country_list_id">   </ul>                 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Model:

```
public function search_field($country_id){
    $this->db->select("destination");
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->like('destination', $country_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return json_encode($query->result_array());
}
```

Controller:

```
public function search_fields(){
         $this->load->helper('form');
    $country_id = $this->input->post('term');
    $data['var']= $this->travel->search_field($country_id);
    echo $data['var'];
}
```

Comment: why does search_fields() has no return statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is coming ok from the server(as a json), try this to create your list:

```
success: function(data) {
    var $countryList = $('#country_list_id');

    // Clear the list
    $countryList.empty();

    // Append all items as <li> elements
    data.forEach(x => {
        $countryList.append("<li>" + x.destination + "</li>");
    });

    // Show the list
    $countryList.show();
}
```

Comment: it will be in controller??

Comment: @HarrisKhan, nope, in your ajax `success` actually.

Comment: data.forEach(x => {
        $countryList.append("<li>" + x.destination + "</li>");
    });

Comment: @HarrisKhan `data` is probably a string. Add to your ajax options `dataType: "json"` so data comes as an object.

Comment: yeah its working :) but I am getting repitition of results means lagos two times, accra 4 times. how to deal with it??

Comment: @HarrisKhan this is probably over your json result, your query or whatever in your server side.. I can't tell as I don't know it.